# How to create a bookmark button using javascript?

Tags: javascript, email

How to create a bookmark button that sends the whole page as email .

Comment: Take a look at the edited version of my post, you'll have to create a hyperlink for the same.

Comment: I know I'm bit late for this ;-) but try the following page. Its the perfect solution to your requirement: http://solutions.weblite.ca/emailwebpage/

Answer (score 3):

HTML content of a page is a bit harder to send, you can use this to send the page's text in an email like this -

```
if (document.all)
    window.open("mailto:email@email.com?body=" + document.body.innerText); //For IE
else
    window.open("mailto:email@email.com?body=" + document.body.textContent); //For FF et al.
```

The bookmark will be -

```
"javascript:if (document.all) window.open('mailto:email@email.com?body=' + document.body.innerText); else window.open('mailto:email@email.com?body=' + document.body.textContent);"
```

EDIT: For this to work, you'll have to create a link, and you'll have to right-click it and click "Add to Favorites".

```
<a href="javascript:if (document.all) window.open('mailto:email@email.com?body=' + document.body.innerText); else window.open('mailto:email@email.com?body=' + document.body.textContent);">Bookmark This</a>
```

Comment: But i am in need of whole content

Answer (score 0):

I played with your question a little bit, done it with jquery ($('html').html()), and everything seemed fine for a moment.. BUT.. after I tried to email the whole content it didn't work either. When I got why it did not work I laughed - url too long, dude, software won't open it. Tested even on hard-coded string - short content opened the mail client fine, long did not.

Forgetaboudit.

If you want to read the html with javascript so hard, you can do it, but you have to send it via post to your server and mail it from there. Cheerz

ps. try with some test short html content and then with a whole casual webpage

```
$(document).ready(function(){           
        $("#testlink").click(function() {
            $('#trick').text($("html").html().replace(/[\r\n]+/g, "%0A"));
            window.open('email@email.com?body='+$('#trick').html(), 'email', '');
        }); 
    });
```

Comment: you mean a bookmarklet? you can load via a bookmarklet whatever you want, it doesn't change the fact that it probably won't work (according to my conclusions). maybe tell us the 'why', this idea is kind of crazy anyway.

Answer (score -3):

Put something like this within the head
section of your HTML document, or better yet, skip the script tags and

put it in an external file and link to it in the head section instead:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="Text/Javascript"><!-- // 
var url = " "; //u can add ur url
var pageName = "Client side programming"; 
function bookmark() { 
if (window.external) { 
window.external.AddFavorite(url, pageName)   
} 
else { 
alert("Sorry! Your browser doesn't support function. 
Use the bookmark option in your browser instead."); 
} 
} // --></script>
```

And this somewhere in the body section of your HTML document:

```
<input type="button" name="Bookmark this page" onclick="bookmark()" />

or...

Simple link:
<a
href="javascript:bookmark()">Click here to bookmark this page
</a>
```

Comment: This will only bookmark the page, but won't send it in an email.